# Convert vim replace to sed / awk in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, vim, sed

I want to add a `;` before every negative value at the end of my data which looks like this:

```
29.01.2019;29.01.2019;KIND;NAME;ITEM;ITEMNUMBER;ITEMORDER;;;;;;;;;;20,00;VAL
29.01.2019;29.01.2019;KIND;NAME;ITEM;ITEMNUMBER;ITEMORDER;012345678;012345678901;FW02ZZZ46847351235;;;;;;;-1,13;;VAL
```

My trial in `vim`:

```
:%s/-\d\{0,5}\,\d\{0,2}/;&\1/g
```

Unfortunately, I can't call this with `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/-\d\{0,5}\,\d\{0,2}/;&\1/g'
```

I get the error message:

```
sed: 1: "s/-\d\{0,5}\,\d\{0,2}/; ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

How do I convert this so that I can call it from the command line/with `sed`?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/-\d{0,5}(,\d{1,2})?/;&/g' file`

Comment: Did this work in vim? Without any capture groups id be surprised if it did

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, it did work. I am not yet very familiar with regular expressions. Do you have a resource in mind, where I could learn more about this in a structured manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/-\d{0,5}(,\d{1,2})?/;&/g'
```

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{0,5}` - 0 to 5 digits
  -`(,\d{1,2})?` - an optional capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d{1,2}`  - 1 or 2 digits.

The `&` in the replacement pattern stands for the whole match value.

See the [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/AJy7vq):

```
s="29.01.2019;29.01.2019;KIND;NAME;ITEM;ITEMNUMBER;ITEMORDER;;;;;;;;;;20,00;VAL
29.01.2019;29.01.2019;KIND;NAME;ITEM;ITEMNUMBER;ITEMORDER;012345678;012345678901;FW02ZZZ46847351235;;;;;;;-1,13;;VAL"
sed -E 's/-\d{0,5}(,\d{1,2})?/;&/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
29.01.2019;29.01.2019;KIND;NAME;ITEM;ITEMNUMBER;ITEMORDER;;;;;;;;;;20,00;VAL
29.01.2019;29.01.2019;KIND;NAME;ITEM;ITEMNUMBER;ITEMORDER;012345678;012345678901;FW02ZZZ46847351235;;;;;;;;-1,13;;VAL
```